# Help identifying a dystopian story with someone traveling to an alternate universe

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

I read the beginning of this book, and I'd like to finish it.
I think the story centered on a scientist, after a nuclear cataclysm, who had tried to help people but everything went wrong, and people were getting killed. I think a rocket or something took him to an alternate reality version of the USA.

I'm pretty sure it had a green cover.

Comment: Can you provide any more information?  Were there any distinguishing characteristics of the different realities?

Comment: When did you read it?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I don't know, I had only started reading it

Comment: @MrLister a few months ago, but I'm pretty sure it was old.

Comment: Are you sure it was a rocket and a nuclear cataclysm? Some aspects of your story are reminiscent of The Lathe of Heaven, but it doesn't seem like a great fit.

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure that it was nuclear, but I am sure about the rocket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the book - it's *Deathlands: Breakthrough* by James Axler.

[image: Deathlands: Breakthrough]